# IE shows error: "Access is denied." for resizeTo() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var newHeight = $(window).height();
var newWidth = $(window).width();

if (newWidth < 633 )
{
  /* newWidth < 650 ? window.innerWidth = 650 : $(window).height();
   newHeight < 400 ? window.innerHeight = 400 : $(window).width(); */

   window.resizeTo(670,newHeight+80);


}

else if (newHeight < 327) {
window.resizeTo(newWidth+18, 400) 
}
```

So, here i dynamically assign height and width as window re-size, but in IE8 at Window.resizeTo(670,newHeight+80); it shows "Access is denied."
it works fine for Window.resizeTo(670,400);

Any solution?? or otherOption of window.resizeTo() ??
There no problem with FireFox and GoogleChrome.

Comment: Just wanted to know, what does this code does `newWidth < 650 ? window.innerWidth = 650 : $(window).height();` ?? Is it a typo or what??

Comment: @mplungjan: u mean no solution for that? actually it works fine in firefox n chrome,and in IE DeveloperTool when i enter resizeTo(650,400); it works..

Comment: @palaѕн::: its other option to get height and width and assign to window size

Comment: @palaѕн is correct, your code is very weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var newHeight = $(window).height();
var newWidth = $(window).width();

if (newWidth < 633 ) {
   newHeight+=80;
   if (newHeight<100) newHeight=100;
   window.resizeTo(670,newHeight);
   alertSize();

}
else if (newHeight < 327) {
   newWidth +=18;
   if (newWith < 100) newWidth=100; 
   window.resizeTo(newWidth, 400) 
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your time and reply @mplungjan, infact i got solution by using SetTimeout function(){.. },500); >>  Sometimes in IE8 the document.domain isn't set fast enough, I've had to call my  functions after a timeout before to get it to work - or I get the same issues again n again.

Comment: Better to use window.onload since you may wait for scrollbars. In any case I would never visit your site again if you resized my window, so I hope this is a popup